# How to process XML using C#?

Tags: c#, html, xml

How do i rename specific nodes? I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work for me. I need a method : replace (oldnode,newnode). 
Here is my code for parsing xml file 

public Recursion ( XmlNode node )
        {
            if ( node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Text )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Tag Name = " + node.Name );
            }

```
        XmlNodeList children = node.ChildNodes;
        foreach ( XmlNode child in children )
        {
            Recursion( child );
        }
    }
```

Comment: u can search it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475293/change-the-node-names-in-an-xml-file-using-c-sharp just try to be resourceful and try to learn from your own first, its fulfilling!

Comment: UP ! UP! UP ! @Euphoria

Answer (score 0):

you need to make A with tag just like < A > To can Catch it by 
if you try to catch A 
You Will Get 
**A**
John K**A**M**A**L
/**A**
but if A With Tag
< **A** >< br >

John< br >

< /**A** > < br >

it easy to replace

Comment: i say if you change A --> < A > you can replace it with < HTML >

Comment: A have to take properties of <HTML>

Comment: try get all code as string then replace < HTML > with A string.Replace

Comment: And the attributes of **A** will be the attributes of <HTML>?

Comment: did you what ti change function what html to make your A do it , or only change in display

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Regex.Replace()?

```
string str = "<html>abc</html>";
str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?:<html>)", "A");
```

The code above will replace all occurrences of `<html>` to A.