# Renaming Xml node

Tags: c#, xml, replace

I try to rename any node starts with "NP" to "NP" in an `XmlDocument`. I only found [this related questoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475293/change-the-node-names-in-an-xml-file-using-c-sharp). based on the most up-voted answer I wrote:

```
 XmlNodeList npNodeList = PSbank.SelectNodes("//*[starts-with(name(), 'NP')]");

foreach (XmlNode npNode in npNodeList)
{

    // create new (renamed) Content node
    XmlNode newNode = PSbank.CreateElement("NP");

    // [if needed] copy existing Content children
    newNode.InnerXml = npNode.InnerXml;

    // replace existing Content node with newly renamed Content node
    npNode.ParentNode.InsertBefore(newNode, npNode);
    npNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(npNode);
}
```

However, it seems it doesn't work in my case. When an `NPX` node contains other `NPX` nodes, the inner nodes are not replaced because the code manipulates `XmlDocument` and replaces the outer node with a new created node that contains the old `innerXml`.

Example Xml:

```
   <S>
     <NPC>
        <NP> A </NP>
        <NPA> B </NPA>
     </NPC>
     <NPD>
         C
     </NPD>
  </S>
```

I look for a more general and elegant answer for such a problem.

Comment: Provide some xml examples, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd do this with LINQ to XML, it's a lot easier and cleaner.  Firstly, it's generally a much nicer library, and secondly: `XElement.Name` is mutable.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);  // or use XDocument.Load

foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    if (element.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("NP"))
    {
        element.Name = "NP";
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wj0zJ2) for a working demo.